# What's the syntax difference of JavaScript between node.js and browsers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Browsers support JavaScript, and Node.js supports it too. I want to know if there any syntax difference between them?

Comment: Strictly speaking, syntax are technically just rules how the tokens can be and those should be the same for everything that claims to be ECMAScript. But some people (especially those who aren't up to their knees in compiler technology) also include how typical usage of the major APIs looks like (on a higher level) in "syntax". Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Node uses [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), which implements the [ECMAScript standard](http://es5.github.com) *(link to non official annotated copy)*.

How it differs from browsers will depend on which browser (and version) you're talking about.

---

For example, Mozilla browsers implement *JavaScript* (which is an implementation and superset of *ECMAScript*).

*JavaScript* includes:

- `for each - in` loops
- destructuring assignment
- `let` expressions
- array comprehensions

...among other enhancements that utilize non *ECMAScript* standard syntax. These are all part of *JavaScript*, but not *currently* part of the *ECMAScript* standard.

*(Of the 4 items listed, the last 3 are proposals for the next ECMAScript version.)*

Comment: More specifically it implements versions of V8

Comment: @Raynos: Thanks, I just caught that flub. :)

Comment: If he really needs DOM functionally in Node.JS he can use https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom (GH is having issue atm).

Comment: More specifically node 0.4.9-0.4.11 use V8 3.1.8.25

Comment: @patrick_dw "these are all part of JavaScript". Here your referring to "JavaScript" as the implementation of ECMAScript that mozilla uses. Even though that's the correct usage of the word JavaScript, most people say "JavaScript" when they actaully mean ECMAScript. I find that saying "part of JavaScript" makes people think it's part of ECMAScript

Comment: @Raynos: Regarding versions, yes the versions of V8 used by the various updates to Node can be seen [in their Change Log](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ChangeLog). *I'm sure you knew that, but for OP.*

Comment: @Raynos: Regarding JavaScript vs ECMAScript, true, but I thought this answer was a good place to illustrate the distinction.

Comment: @patrick_dw the distinction is worth illustration, I'd just recommend mentioning that JavaScript is mozillas implementation and not an alternative word for ECMAScript.

Comment: @Raynos: Fair point. Looking at my answer I'm not explicit enough considering the widespread assumption that the two words are synonymous. I'll update.

Answer (score 8):

No. The Syntax is exactly the same. There are differences in the apis however. The standard browser dom is not available in node but it has additional apis found at [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org). Any syntax differences are due to quirks in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

No. The syntax is exatcly the same, but you're working it provides with different environment - for example, you don't have DOM and have API for file system access and sockets.